# How to create a jQuery Mobile theme

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, themes, jquery-mobile

How do I create a jQueryMobile theme?

Is it overriding the CSS the best way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The best method for creating a theme is actually modifying the existing one. Just like Jquery Mobile have done with their "Valenica" Theme.
Use the standard css as a starting point / reference

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css

Often the best way to work out which elements need the styling tweaks is to inspect them via Firebug

---

Its also worth noting, its not a great idea to try and create a theme from scratch, as a large part of what makes jquery mobile so great is the cross browser testing and developments they have already made to the css.

---

**Update:**

In the near future there will be a jquery mobile theme roller, you can track its development at github.

[https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Mobile-ThemeRoller)

---

**Update 2**

The theme roller is ready!

http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

Comment: +1 I was also looking for this info. But can i copy default and make my theme ans use as a "j"

Comment: Like in jquery mobile we use different type of themes using HTML 5 data attributes. jQuery Mobile's default Theme includes 5 swatches that are given letters (a, b, c, d, e) for quick reference.

Comment: Simple, copy any of the existing styles and change the letter in the classes. ie .  J Styles - .ui-btn-up-j {}

Answer (score 8):

Just discovered a neat tool for creating prototypes which includes its own theme-maker/roller.  Worth checking out! More for the themes than the prototyping. At least until the official themeroller comes out.
http://www.mobjectify.com

Allows you to easily add extra JqueryMobile themes and see it live.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an article I wrote for IBM with this exact title: [Create custom jQuery mobile themes](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/mo-jquery-mobile-themes/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had a chance to test the results of this [theme roller](http://as001.productscape.com/themeroller.cfm); but I thought it might be useful, at least until the official themeroller is available.