# jQuery Mobile Color Swatches

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am aware that you can create custom color swatches to be used with jQuery mobile.  However I am not a designer and would like to find some additional ones to download.  I have searched high and low on google, does anyone have a link to where I can download some that people have released?  I don't mind paying for them if necessary.

Comment: Official jQM Theme Roller released, updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/10/28/announcing-themeroller-for-mobile-beta/

jQM Team plans to release a Theme Roller:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Mobile-ThemeRoller

But here are a couple of other ideas as well:

- http://www.mobjectify.com/
- http://jquerymobile.com/test/themes/valencia/ (via: [How to create a jQuery Mobile theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328001/how-to-create-a-jquery-mobile-theme))
- http://www.jqmgallery.com/ (see what others have done)

Other than this you will need to create your own custom theme as of now